# Including files needed for FindBugs analysis from sibling gradle modules

Tags: java, gradle, findbugs, spotbugs

I have a gradle module that has a compile-time dependency on a sibling module.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':sibling-module')
}
```

While running the build, FindBugs can't seem to find the dependency, so I receive the following message:

```
The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
  com.example.siblingmodule.classname
```

What do I need to do to include these files so that FindBugs can evaluate them?  I am using FindBugs 3.0.1 and gradle 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, and thank you to @webdizz for pointing me in the right direction.  The solution was to add the sibling module **output** to the findbugs classpath.  I did so with the following addition to the complaining module's `build.gradle`:

```
findbugsMain {
    classpath += project(':sibling-module').sourceSets.main.output
}
```

The important bit was to include the `main.output`, and not just the `main.allSource`.

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like Gradle has no property to configure classpath for FindBugs however it still has a `sourceSets` property to specify source code folder to analyse.

Please check [FindBugs configuration object for Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugsExtension.html) for more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the sibling module to the source set `findbugs {sourceSets = [sourceSets.main, sourceSets.test, project(':sibling-module').sourceSets.main]}` did not work, nor did adding the sibling module as a testCompile dependency.

Comment: Nor did adding to the findbugsMain classpath: `findbugsMain {
    classpath += project(':sibling-module').sourceSets.main.allSource
}`